# Invalid token 'base' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, abstract-class, derived-class, base-class

I am not sure what the problem is but what I'm trying to do is to pass argument to a base constructor from a derived class's

error:

`Invalid token 'base' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

here is my `base class code:`

```
public class EmployeeRegistrationBase
{
    //constructor
    public EmployeeRegistrationBase(string methodName)
    {
       //more code...
    }
}
```

here is my `derived class:`

```
public class USER_REG_LOG_INFO  : base(EmployeeRegistrationBase("some_method_name"))
{
     //more code....
}
```

Comment: You should use `base` on Constructors....

Comment: That's not valid syntax.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for inheritance and the constructor passthrough are incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
public class USER_REG_LOG_INFO  : EmployeeRegistrationBase
{
     public USER_REG_LOG_INFO() : base("some_method_name")
     {
     }

     //more code....
}
```